# can't access fromAsset method of FragmentProgram class, Flutter

Tags: flutter, shader

I'm trying to write some custom graphics stuff, but got stuck at loading shaders.

I have this:

```
void loadMyShader() async {
   var program = await FragmentProgram.fromAsset('shaders/myshader.frag');
}
```

from the webpage: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/advanced/shaders

in VSCode, but I get an undefined method error for .fromAsset()

The above function definition is inside a simple class.
The only method that gets suggested is .compile(), but that expects some spirv code I don't know.
Is it an issue with the api being beta, or something completely obvious I'm missing here?

I haven't compiled the code, I just see the error message described above.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to upgrade flutter. 3.7.7 has it

Answer (score 0):

In your `pubspec.yaml` change the location of where you list your shaders from `assets:` to `shaders:`. your final yaml should look like this:

```
  assets:
    - assets/fonts/
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/images/

  shaders:
    - assets/shaders/simple.frag
    - assets/shaders/toon_cloud.frag
```